# How to get field value from multiple items? Twig

Tags: paragraphs

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

I need to get some values from fields in item (displayed in screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Example -

```
{{ item.content['#paragraph'].field_NAME.value }}
```

original source - https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2018-08-01/get-reference-entity-values-in-field-level-twig-template